# Shortcut for .mp3 .jpg .docx files

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts

Is it possible to have a shortcut on home screen for  .mp3, .jpg, .docx etc  files . As I need to access few documents every now and then , for this I have to go through folders in my ext memory.